# Pass common params to all states UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

I am a newbie in UI router. I need to pass a global param to all my states. Is there any way as config to have global params in UI Router?

Comment: `url: '/party/2',` 2 is a GLOBAL PARAM and you would change party state

Comment: In the url of each state, I shouldn't set 2. I need a common place where I could set the key for global param and all the states can either have it or not. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer it in this way. extend the `$stateParam`

```
app.factory('ExtendedStateParam', function($http, $stateParam, $state){
  $stateParam['global_param'] = $state.$current.global_param;
  return $stateParam;
}
```

Comment: Thats cool. But, the "bla" value may vary. Its from the url the user hits, how can I get that?

Comment: it's updated. Inject $state into the factory and then use `$state.$current.global_param`

Comment: Thank you. Should I call this factory in the controllers or this declaration is alone enough?

Comment: I cannot get this working, could you please post Plunker or something? I am trying to achieve back() functionality and pass extra parameters, and I want all states have common 'extra' parameter. Thanks.